# python loop through list through regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, for-loop

I am trying to iterate a list with for loop and build a second list through regex capture group. I looked through documentation related to the re module but for some reason, the regex always return one result. The regex was tested so I am certain that is works.

Any thoughts?

*Edited*

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import re
import subprocess
try:
    cmd = "ps aux|grep -i \'zabbi[x]\'"
    cmd_stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).split('\n')
    cmd_stdout_lst = []
    ps_re = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\.\d+\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+).+')
    for line in cmd_stdout:
        match = ps_re.findall(line)
        if match:
            print match
        cmd_stdout_lst.append('\n\t\t{"{#USER}":'+'"' + match[0][0] + ',"{#PID}":'+'"'+match[0][1]+'"}'+',"{#PID}":'+'"'+match    [0][2]+'"}'+',"{#PID}":'+'"'+match[0][3]+'"}')
    print '{\n\t"data":['+','.join(cmd_stdout_lst)+']\n}'
except:
    raise

$ python proc_discovery.py
[('zabbix', '14479', '96784', '680')]
```

Comment: The expected output should be a new json list, something like this:

`{"data":[{"{#USER}":"zabbix"},{"{#PID}":"14479"},{"{#VSZ}":"96784"},{"{#RSS}":"680"}]}`

Comment: switch your `except: exit(1)` to `except: raise` (or just remove it entirely) so you aren't hiding the exception you're getting. That is your problem. You're probably getting list index out of range exceptions.

Comment: Yes I suspect the match group is the issue, but when I thought match group is a list?!
    
`$ python proc_discovery.py
        [('zabbix', '14479', '96784', '680')]
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "proc_discovery.py", line 15, in <module>
            print match[2]
        IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Also, remember: [using a bare `except:` is almost never a good idea.](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two things wrong with this:

1. Your grep regex matches the same thing as simply `zabbix` would. Why the extra `[ ]`?
2. Your program crashes after the first `print` inside the loop. You don't notice because you catch and ignore the exception. Remove the `try`-`except` to get a more helpful error message.

Specifically, problem number 2 is that `re.findall()` returns a `list` of `tuple`s. The outer `list` has a single element in your case, the inner `tuple`s have four. When you try to build the string for the second print statement, you are actually concatenating the entire tuple to the prefix string, which causes the exception. Use `match[0][0]` instead of`match[0]` and so on, to fix this.

Comment: That's it!

1. I added the square bracket so the grep command doesn't show up on the list.

2. I didn't aware I am working on multi-dimentional list as I assume I am always working on the inner list.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's a clever way to avoid the grep process itself showing up in the output :)